# How to update spyder standalone application

Tags: spyder

How can i update spyder using CMD. I have decided to use Spyder standalone and I am not using Anaconda, as I don't need the rest of the package. No i need to update it, but I can't find the option.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it's:

```sh
pip install -u spyder
```